# Expectation of exponential of lognormal distributed random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, exponential-function

Why do we have that $$\mathbb{E}[\exp(\exp(Y))]=\infty$$
where $Y$ is Gaussian distributed? This is stated in a book, but what is a proof? Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why it is not the case for that $X$.

Comment: $E(e^{e^Y})=C\int \exp(e^y-y^2/2)$ and the exponent diverges.

Comment: More generally, $E(\exp(f(Y)))$ doesn't exists if $f(y)-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$ doesn't go to $-\infty$ as $y\to\infty$.